# storing php objects on html form element and passing php objects through GET method?

Tags: php, forms

I might sound a bit weird but, is there a way? For example, I have a PHP object `$foo`.

Is there a way to store this object in an HTML form (hidden input) by some object encrypting function and later retrieved with decryption function.

Similarly, can I pass these objects through GET method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like pointed out elsewhere already, you can use serialize to turn the object into a string.

```
$foo = (object) array(
    'foo' => 'foo & bär',
    'bar' => new StdClass
);

$serialized = serialize($foo);
```

This gives:

```
O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:3:"foo";s:10:"foo & bär";s:3:"bar";O:8:"stdClass":0:{}}
```

As you can see there is quotes in that string, so you cannot insert that into a link without risking breaking your markup:

```
<a href="http://example.com?s=O:8:" <-- quote closes href
```

So at the very least you'd have to [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) that output. However, that would still leave the content easily readable. You could make use of [PHP's MCrypt library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) to put some strong encryption on the string. But if the data really is *that* sensitive, you should probably find another means of transferal, away from the public facing portion of your site.

If the data is less sensitive, then you can probably safe some CPU cycles by just obfuscating the string. The easiest way to do that is to run it through [`gzdeflate`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php):

```
echo gzdeflate(serialize($foo));
```

gives something like

```
R*.Iq�I,.V�2��.�2�RJ��W�.�24 …
```

Using `gzdeflate` will also shorten large serialized strings. The drawback is, it produces output unfit for transferal via HTTP, so you also have to [`base64_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) that:

```
echo base64_encode(gzdeflate(serialize($foo)));
```

which will then give

```
87eysFIqLklxzkksLlayMrKqLrYytlJKy89Xsi62MjQAMxXUFJIOLykCiQDlkhKBLH9UfQZW1bW1AA==
```

And that's safe for transferal and also pretty obfuscated from the original serialized string. Because we have compressed the string before we base64'ed it, anyone smart enough to figure out it's base64 will still have to make sense of the compressed string when trying to reverse it.

To turn the string back into an object, you then do

```
unserialize(
    gzinflate(
        base64_decode(
            $obfuscatedString
        )
    )
)
```

and get your object back. [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ouK8Lu)

---

**A note on Security**

The above is still insecure. You should not rely on obfuscation for security. If you transfer an object or an entire object graph via HTTP, you have to consider them as user input on the receiving end. **User input cannot be trusted**. Malicious users figuring out how the string was obfuscated can provide an altered input. Because you are unserializing objects back into the program flow, you have to be absolutely paranoid about the resulting object.

See http://www.sektioneins.com/en/advisories/advisory-032009-piwik-cookie-unserialize-vulnerability/ for a related example.

Answer (score 3):

If it doesn't contain sensitive data you could [`serialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) it (or even optionally encrypt the serialized data), for example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(serialize($foo), ENT_QUOTES); ?>" />
```

In the receiving script, [`unseralize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) the POST data to get back the object:

```
$foo = unserialize($_POST['foo']);
```

Comment: Probably also needs escaping after serialization, but before echoing to protect against script / HTML injection and such, i.e. `htmlspecialchars(serialize($foo))`. To get the value in PHP requires that you have sent that form to PHP first, then you can read it out via `unserialize($_POST['foo'])` (or `unserialize($_GET['foo'])` if you sent via GET)- Note however, that `unserialize()` has exposed security issues in the past if I remember correctly, so that might be dangerous, and you will also have to check if unserialization actually worked.

Comment: In my case the var_dump of unserialization is "bool(false)".
What could be going wrong ? I am using form variable value as ..
value="<?php echo htmlentities( serialize($loggedInUser_NP_MatchupObj) ); ?>"

Comment: I also used htmlspecialchars(..) exactly as mentioned in your code above, but then also the result of unserializing is false.. I am trying to pass a custom php object via the value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `serialize` and `unserialize` methods:

```
$serialized = serialize($foo);
```

Now you can store `$serialized` in your hidden input field. Later, you can read it back and convert to object with `unserialize` method. For example:

```
$foo = unserialize($_POST['my_hidden_field']); // back to object
```