# Save php object in client side

Tags: javascript, php, html, client-side

Is there any way to save a php object in the client side, so when I further need it I don't need to make Ajax request to get another new.

Comment: look into [localStorage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage)

Comment: A PHP object, no. An equivalent JavaScript object to the PHP object, yes. It also depends on what exactly you mean by "save". If you are getting the data from the server, it is stored in memory, so you always have access to it, as long as the page "lives". Or are you asking for persisting storage between page loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -- use an [HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) key to save whatever data you need:

```
localStorage["hi"] = "ho";

// and then later ...
alert(localStorage["hi"]);
```

Strings saved into the browser's local storage will persist when the user navigates to a new page on your site, or returns to your site later.  Its browser support is pretty good -- even IE8+ supports it.

One note: you can only save string data.  So, if you have an object, then you'll need to use JSON.stringify / JSON.parse:

```
var user = { firstName: "foo", lastName: "bar" };
localStorage["name"] = JSON.stringify(user);

// and then later ...
var restoredUser = JSON.parse(localStorage["name"]);
if (restoredUser)
    alert("Hi, " + restoredUser.firstName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use object `serialization/deserazlization` as explained here [storing php objects on html form element and passing php objects through GET method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842140/storing-php-objects-on-html-form-element-and-passing-php-objects-through-get-met)

- `serialize` the object and encrypt the output xml string that goes on client
- Then when client send request back you can decrypt the xml string and restore the object on server side by using `deserialization`

About encryption see this one [Simplest two-way encryption using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262109/php-simplest-two-way-encryption)

And also you can use HTML 5 client local storage as said above but this may not work in older browsers by default see [localStorage supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage)

And again it is really depends on what you exactly want to achieve and what kind of data you want to store, in some cases you can just simply use server caching so in such case you do not need to store the whole object on the client at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you **can certainly store a PHP object** at the client side. Eve an object, which contains references to object, arrays as member variables...

> But **don't trust anything** coming back from the client that you
>   forwarded before to the client!

An attacked can easily change or replace the serialized object at the client side. Therefore, **it's extremely dangerous** to store server-side objects at the client side.

**That said, here is how to store a PHP object at the client side**

First, **serialize** the object:

```
$serializedObject = serialize( $someObject );
```

Next, **save the object using [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)** at the client side (base64_encode() 'hides' quotes):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  localStorage["soAccessor"] 
      = "<?php echo base64_encode( $serializedObject ); ?>";
</script>
```

Finally, you might pass it back to the PHP-side using e.g. a hidden field of a form.

In case you need to deserialize something back to its original object state, use [deserialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php). Note, that you need to `require_once()` each object's class definition before doing the deserialize operation.

During deserialization, PHP tries to `__wakeup()` serialized objects. This won't happen correctly, if the class isn't orderly defined yet.